# arithm_op Error in Fisheye Calibration of OpenCV python Bindings

Tags: python, opencv, calibration, fisheye

I got this error and I cant resolve this error.
I guess the error is related to optimizing module and caused by type of input vector.
But I cant resolve it!!!
Please give me a solution.

cv2 version is 3.1.0
python 3.5

### below is my code

```
import cv2
assert cv2.__version__[0] == '3', 'The fisheye module requires opencv version >= 3.0.0'
import numpy as np
import os

CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
subpix_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW
objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
_img_shape = None
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

pict_dir = './pics/chess_boads_2/fish_eye/'
images = [ pict_dir + f for f in os.listdir(pict_dir) if "JPG" in f][:1]


for fname in images:

    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (500,500))

    if _img_shape == None:
        _img_shape = img.shape[:2]
    else:
        assert _img_shape == img.shape[:2], "All images must share the same size."
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
    print("->",ret)


    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (6,9), corners,ret)

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

N_OK = len(objpoints)
K = np.zeros((3, 3))
D = np.zeros((4, 1))
D = np.zeros(4)
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]

rms, _, _, _, _ = \
    cv2.fisheye.calibrate(
        objpoints,
        imgpoints,
        gray.shape[::-1],
        K,
        D
    )


print("Found " + str(N_OK) + " valid images for calibration")
print("DIM=" + str(_img_shape[::-1]))
print("K=np.array(" + str(K.tolist()) + ")")
print("D=np.array(" + str(D.tolist()) + ")")
```

### and I got this output and error

```
-> True

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f52039dc56d0> in <module>()
     62         gray.shape[::-1],
     63         K,
---> 64         D
     65     )
     66 

error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:639: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op'
```

I changed code repeatedly. and I find out the error occurs in  cv2.fisheye.calibrate() .
but I dont know how I fix it.

Comment: Works fine for me. Python 3.6.6, OpenCV 3.4.2.

Comment: thanks i will try other versions !

Comment: I tried this code in Python 3.6.6 and OpenCV 3.4.1 and I found the code worked well.
so, newer version solved this problem!!